# Pyspark error handling with file name having spaces

Tags: python, regex, hadoop, pyspark

I am using `pyspark 2.1`

Problem Statement: Need to validate the `hdfs path`, file if exist need to copy file name into variable

Below is the code used so far after referring few websites and `stackoverflow`

```
import os
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import times
def run_cmd(args_list):
     print('Running system command: {0}'.format(' '.join(args_list)))
     proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
     proc.communicate()
     return proc.returncode

 today = datetime.now().date().strftime('%d%b%Y')
 source_dir = '/user/dev/input/'+ today
 hdfs_file_path=source_dir+'\'student marks details.csv\''
 cmd = ['hdfs', 'dfs', '-find','{}','-name', hdfs_file_path]
 code=run_cmd(cmd)
 if code<>1:
    print 'file doesnot exist'
    System.exit(1)
 else:
    print 'file exist'
```

With above code I am getting error as "File doesn't exist" but file is present in that folder

Problem is able to run the run below command in shell console I am getting the complete path.

```
hdfs dfs -find () -name /user/dev/input/08Aug2017/'student marks details.csv'
```

When I tried to import in pyspark with above detailed code I am not able to execute as there exist space in an filename . Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: If you find that my answer helped you solve your problem, please go ahead and accept it (or upvote it). That's what StackOverflow [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

Your problem is on this line:

```
 hdfs_file_path = source_dir + '\'student marks details.csv\''
```

You are adding two unneeded single quotes, and also forgetting to add a directory separator.

The reason the path works in this command:

```
hdfs dfs -find () -name /user/dev/input/08Aug2017/'student marks details.csv'
```

is because this is a **shell** command. On the shell that you are using (presumably it is [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)), the following commands are equivalent:

```
echo '/user/dev/input/08Aug2017/student marks details.csv'
echo /user/dev/input/08Aug2017/'student marks details.csv'
```

bash removes the quotes, and merges the strings together, yielding the same string result, which is `/user/dev/input/08Aug2017/student marks details.csv`. The quotes are not actually part of the path, but just a way to tell bash to not split the string at the spaces, but create a single string, and then remove the quotes.

When you write:

```
 hdfs_file_path = source_dir + '\'student marks details.csv\''
```

The path you end up getting is `/user/dev/input/08Aug2017'student marks details.csv'`, instead of the correct `/user/dev/input/08Aug2017/student marks details.csv`.

The `subprocess` call just requires plain strings that correspond to the values that you want, and will not process them the same way the shell does.

#### Solution

In python, joining paths together is best performed by calling [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). So I would suggest to replace these lines:

```
source_dir = '/user/dev/input/' + today
hdfs_file_path = source_dir + '\'student marks details.csv\''
```

with the following:

```
source_dir = os.path.join('/user/dev/input/', today)
hdfs_file_path = os.path.join(source_dir, 'student marks details.csv')
```

`os.path.join` takes care to add a single directory separator (/ on Unix, \ on Windows) between its arguments, so you can't accidentally either forget the separator, or add it twice.